# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I understand I can use `validateRequest="false"` to by pass ASP.NET security. I'd like to know what security issues setting this flag may cause. Can I be 100% sure there won't be any issue as long as I encode the input using a XSS library?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, this validation protects only from '<' and '>' characters, and therefore you are protected form e.g. someone putting <script> alert('f word')</script> in your blog post comment...

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn it off in a few applications and (as mentioned) as long as you [do encode your output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx#paght000004_step5) you should be fine. And request validation should not be your only weapon [for XSS prevention - How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx).

On the other hand *if* you are [using MVC3 you can disable request validation at a more granular level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx)

Comment: Did you intend to write "You should trust request validation **only** for XSS prevention"?  Rather than "should **not** "?

Comment: @AaronL I meant to point out the other methods against XSS. Do you think it reads a bit clearer now?

Comment: Yes clearer now.  I had thought you were trying to make the point that there are other threats like CSRF that validateRequest doesn't really help with anyway(as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you properly encode data displayed in the resulting HTML page you are pretty safe.

Comment: What about data that is not displayed? I wonder why the Validate Request mechanism is so proactive in posting values with illegal characters as most of the time I am not outputting them on the webpage.

Comment: @DotnetDude, displaying is a sort of processing the data: you are passing it to some external system (a web browser) which might execute dangerous scripts. So as long as you properly encode the data for the external system you are passing this data to you are safe.